# How do you add values to AutoForm's form object without using a form?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I've got a form created through AutoForm.

As far as data sources, I can fill in parts of the form and use:

```
AutoForm.getFormValues('form-id').insertDoc // returns the contents of the form
```

When I validate the form I can do:

```
var formValues = AutoForm.getFormValues('form-id').insertDoc;

var isValid = MyCollection.simpleSchema().namedContext("myContext").validate(formValues); 

// if isValid returns true, then I enable the Submit button
```

Instead of filling in parts of the form, I want to manually add information into whatever object Autoform uses for validation and submission to a collection.

For example, there are data fields in the schema that simply don't need to appear in the form itself.

Take a shopping cart:

```
ShoppingCartSchema = {
  totalPrice: {
    type: Number,
    optional: false
  },
  itemsSelected: {
    type: [Object],
    optional: false
  }
};
```

The data for `itemsSelected` is obviously provided through user input on the form.

The data for `totalPrice` is something that should not be from a form input. It's generated in the code.

But `totalPrice` still needs to be validated as a required field before AutoForm submits the form to a collection.

So how do you add `totalPrice` onto the object that Autoform eventually validates?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an autovalue if you wanted to.

```
ShoppingCartSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  'items': {
    type: [Object],
  },
  'items.$.name': {
    type: String
  },
  'items.$.price': {
    type: Number
  },
  totalPrice: {
    type: Number,
    autoValue: function () {
      if (this.field('items').isSet) {
        let total = this.field('items').value.reduce(function (sum, item) {
          return sum + item.price;
        }, 0);
        if (this.isInsert) {
          return total;
        } else {
          return { $set: total };
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Autoform Hooks can help you manipulate the data before you save it into the Collection.

In your case .

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  form-id: { // The Autoform ID
    onSubmit: function (insertDoc, updateDoc, currentDoc) {
      if (customHandler(insertDoc)) { // Your Logic here
        this.done(); // This is Required
      } else {
        this.done(new Error("Submission failed"));
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

For More Information Please refer [Autoform Readme](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform)

Comment: Well, in my case the hooks will be coming too late. I have a `Submit` button that should be enabled only if the form is valid, which means the `totalPrice` value must exist. But `totalPrice` can't actually appear as a field on the form. I could create a hidden form field just for `totalPrice`, but I would *highly* prefer to do it another way. I have lots of other fields that can't appear on the form but still need to be validated before the `Submit` button can be activated.

Comment: If Fields are auto populated by the code then probably we dont need to validate them(I dont know you Business Requirement), hence Submit button can be activated  without checking `totalPrice`. or other hidden attributes